# Yucca – brown mushy spots on the leaves

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, growth, sunlight, palm

We have given our Yucca's new flower soil. Now they have mushy brown spots on the leaves. Before, they stood in the living room without direct sun. Now they are outside (sun in the day (morning 2 hours and evening 3 hours) and at night about 16 ° Celsius).

Do they need more water because of the sunshine? Normally, they do not need much water. Are the temperature fluctuations not good? Sunlight and at night 16 ° C?

An idea what caused these brown spots?

Our dragon trees have similar problems.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Gardening Know How](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/foliage/yucca/yucca-turning-brown.htm) "Yucca Plant Problems: Why A Yucca Plant Has Brown Tips Or Foliage" suggests water quality may be the issue:

> - **Fluoride toxicity**
>     When your yucca plant has brown tips, it’s likely due to fluoride toxicity. This issue generally starts as small brown spots on leaf margins, but soon encompasses the entire leaf tip. It’s especially bad on older leaves. There’s no serious risk with fluoride toxicity, but it does make a yucca look unsightly. Switch to watering with distilled water and the problem will clear up over time.
> - **Salt toxicity**
>     Although fluoride isn’t a huge threat to your plant’s health, salt is a serious problem. If you live where the soil has a high salinity level, or you water from a water softener, your plant may respond with stunted growth, browning tips and leaf margins or other leaf-related issue. In very salty conditions, a white crust may form at the surface of the soil. You can attempt to flush the soil with salt-free water, but unless you act quickly, your yucca may be beyond saving.

Whatever "flower soil" is, it may be too rich for a plant suited to arid conditions short on nutrients. During the summer yuccas need *less* water.